# How to create a Git Branch with an empty commit on it?

Tags: git

I am a very specific custom requirement for my team that every time they create a git branch from the `main` branch they are forced to create a empty commit on it with a message, which they have to fill up.

I looked and search on Google but didn't fidn anything that Git supports out of box, AFAIK. Is there a way to do this with some custom actions?

Here is what I am asking by graph:

```
[a]-->[b]-->[c]-->[d]-->[e] *main-branch*
                         \
                          [empty-commit with message prompt to fill-in]--> *custom-branch*
```

Comment: Like the `--allow-empty` switch available on [git-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)? How would you enforce it? It would make more sense (imo) to just not push branches untill they have specific commits on them

Comment: `git commit --allow-empty`.... but that thing about creating an empty revision just to set up the branch sounds so **svnish**....

Comment: This is going to end up being an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would recommend you post another question with the problem you are trying to solve, to which someone decided an empty commit on new branches was the best solution. I'm fairly certain you'll receive answers with much better solutions to that problem than empty commits.

Comment: There is no X-Y problem. This is the question. I think this a very fundamental requirement, creating a branch with empty commit message. I am surprised why no one felt the need to do that. Also to my surprise, seems like it is very easy to implement that inside git. Will give a shot.

Comment: I agree this is the question. (That's why I said to create a new question.) If nothing else, I'm curious to know what creating the empty commits is for.

Comment: Sure, it's easy: `git switch -c testing && git commit --allow-empty -m "A new branch!"` If you want to get prompted for the message, just leave off the message part (-m "blah blah"). But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Often when developers starts a project they have the end goal in mind and the requirements are pretty much reader oriented, and clear from a high level. This changes after months of hard work, they get too detail into the problem and then most of the time details remains very dev focused. They don’t talk the same language and hence the commits are very cryptic. With an empty commit, dev can send out a consumer centric commit message  to their branch which remains at the top of their branch and if they require to squash and merge every, the final commit remains human readable.

Comment: I am expecting something like ```git branch branch_name -m “Creating a new feature”``` would be very convenient.

Comment: That's the command I gave you except you check out the branch instead of make it off to the side. AFAIK there is no way to create a branch and create a commit in 1 command. But you can do it on one line with `&&`.

Comment: I understand that, but this sounds almost like ```git fetch && git merge```, instead of ```git pull``` is which is very user friendly.

Comment: Regarding the "why", ok, I get it now. It's pretty common to have some other tool that tracks stories for you, and perhaps you name the branch with the story number so the "What am I trying to do" is captured outside of the repo. The commit messages themselves would explain "What each commit does." If you don't have a tool outside of the repo, and you can't use one (which I would find hard to believe), then I see some value in the empty commits. But I would much prefer that info in another tool, preferably the same tool used for PR discussions.

Comment: What if the PR tool and the git server are same tool? We exactly have that in place.

Comment: Note that *as asked*, this really *is* an X-Y problem. It's just that you have problem X++, not problem X. You're asking for details about solution Y to problem X++ (a system where you use Git as your bug tracker as well as your source control), and couching it as a question about X (Git without the bug-tracker aspect). This is mild, as X-Y issues go, but if you'd said that up front it *might* have resulted in less commentary. :-)

Comment: @kishoredbn What SCM are you using? Most of the popular ones have some sort of project management capabilities such as stories or issues. If yours doesn't or you're using a free tier that doesn't offer it, there are many free project management tools available. One of the downsides of using commits for this is that stories and issues tend to evolve over time, but commits are immutable (so you have to rewrite often- not a huge deal in itself but perhaps tedious.) And, you miss out on screenshots to help describe the goal, assigning to devs, status updates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comments, you are not so much looking for a way to *force* developers to do this, but to make it *convenient* for them to do so. For that, I would suggest an alias. For example, if you have them create a `new-branch` alias like so:

```
git config alias.new-branch '!f() { git checkout -b ${1};  git commit --allow-empty -m "${2}"; }; f'
```

Then they can create a new branch *and* a single, empty commit on that branch with:

```
git new-branch some-new-branch "here is the comment of the empty commit"
```